# Using pythonnet to pass stream to .net DLL

Tags: stream, python.net

I'm working with a .NET DLL file processor, but can't seem to get the stream passing working. I have the following relevant methods.

```
EmbedFile(string): bool
EmbedFile(Stream): bool
```

When using the string version, it works as expected when given a filename.

```
encoder.EmbedFile("test.dat")
```

However, I'm not sure what to pass to the stream version. I've tried io.BytesIO and a file handle, but both give me the following.

```
TypeError: No method matches given arguments for EmbedFile
```

What is the correct oject to pass to a .NET method that takes a Stream parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late reply, but have you tried importing a .NET class that inherits from Stream, then constructing an instance in Python.

```py
import clr
from System import File
from System.IO import FileStream

def main():   
    path = "path\\to\\file.dat"

    clrFile = File(path)

    clrFileStream = FileStream(clrFile)

    returnValue = EmbedFile(clrFileStream)
```

Note: this could require additional import(s) if more .NET parameters are present in the derived Stream's constructor.